# Deleting all folders older than a specified date, except some of them

Tags: bash, directory, date

i had to do a script job in bash to delete all directory in a path which are older than a specified date except some of them. 
i know the name of the directories which shouldn't be deleted...

Can you help me???

i'm sorry but i'm a beginner...

lot of thanks!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794479/deleting-all-folders-older-than-a-specified-date-except-some).

Answer (score 3):

This must be my find day.

`find /yourpath -mmin +60 -type d -not \( -name dirname1 -o -name dirname2 \) -print0 | xargs -0 rm -r`

will find and delete all directories older than 60 minutes (adapt accordingly) which are not named `dirname1` or `dirname2`. You can extend this list  with additional `-o name dirname` parts. Also, I would strongly recommend to replace the `rm -r` part with echo for testing.

Comment: Cool, more elegant than what I was going to propose (shell hack)

Comment: it'll be perfect even if my version don't understand "-not"

Answer (score 2):

try tmpwatch with the exclude options -x and -X

man tmpwatch for more info.

I've never used it myself with the excludes so i cant provide examples, but im pretty sure that'll work.

Comment: sorry i've not tmpwatch on my version...

Comment: @mikjcl https://fedorahosted.org/tmpwatch/ <- Easy enough to install -- and a better option than the ghetto solution I'm about to post

Answer (score 1):

For GNU `find`:

```
find . ! -newermt 2010/10/01 -type d -regextype posix-egrep ! -regex '^.*/(foo|bar|baz)/?.*' -exec echo rm -rf {} +
```

This will find and delete directories older than the given date that do not match the regular expression. Change "foo", etc., to match your directory names. Separate each name using `|`. Remove the `echo` when you're finished testing. The modification time is checked, change to `-newerat` to check the access time instead.